# Updating State Array from nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, state

So, I have an array of objects, each with an INTELLCONT property. Some of these properties are an array of more than one element, some are just a single object.

I want to iterate through each one and add it to my results state array that get's passed down to another component. I am only getting the last 4 nested INTELLCONT elements in my results array (there are 16 total INTELLCONT elements). My console.log() functions log all 16 values so I know I can access them correctly.

Why are only some of my elements being added to the results array?

EDIT: Upon closer look at the console. It looks like each time hit swaps from the IF to the ELSE statement (or vice versa) it replaces all the values in the array (or makes a new one?). i.e. 3 nested values are replaced by one not nested value and then that one value is replaced by 4 not nested values. Still not sure what the problem is though!

Thanks!

```
if (resultData) {
    resultData.forEach(function(element) {
        if (element.INTELLCONT.length > 1) {
            element.INTELLCONT.forEach(function(nested) {
            console.log(nested.TITLE._text);
                    const newResults = element.INTELLCONT.map(result => (
                        {
                ...results,
                title: result.TITLE._text,
            }));
            setResults(newResults);
        });
        } else {
            console.log(element.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text);
            const newResults = [
            ...results,
                { title: element.INTELLCONT.TITLE._text },
            ];
            setResults(newResults);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're spreading the `results` array in each new object when you're mapping `element.INTELLCONT`.

Comment: Is that not the proper way to add a new result to the array?

Comment: Spreading an _array_ inside an _array_, then adding another value would create a shallow copy with additional items. Spreading an _array_ inside an _object_ adds properties with the index as a key, which is just a bunch of numbers and then `title`. You probably want to spread `result` which is probably the object you want to merge.